# "errorMessage":"Cannot find module 'C:\\Users\\vickey\\Downloads\\RFREARN_BACKEND\\RFREARN_BACKEND\\routes\\passport-config'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lambda, passport.js

**Description:**
I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js/ESM project running on AWS Serverless Architecture. The error message indicates that it cannot find the 'passport-config' module. I've thoroughly checked the path, dependencies, and tried different import/export methods, but the problem persists.

**Code Samples:**

1. **passport-config.js**

   ```js
   // passport-config.js

   import passport from 'passport';
   import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
   import dotenv from 'dotenv';

   dotenv.config();

   passport.use(
     new GoogleStrategy(
       {
         clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
         clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
         callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
         scope: ["profile", "email"],
         state: false
       },
       async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, callback) => {
         return callback(null, profile);
       }
     )
   );

   export default passport;
   // userRoutes.js
   ```

import express from 'express';
import passport from './passport-config';
import userController from '../controllers/userController';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/error', session: false }),
(req, res) => {
res.redirect('/auth/google/success');
});

router.use('/auth/google/success', userController.googleSignUp);

export default router;

**Error Stack Trace:**

{"errorMessage":"Cannot find module 'C:\Users\vickey\Downloads\RFREARN_BACKEND\RFREARN_BACKEND\helpers\passport-config' imported from C:\Users\vickey\Downloads\RFREARN_BACKEND\RFREARN_BACKEND\routes\userRoutes.js","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\vickey\Downloads\RFREARN_BACKEND\RFREARN_BACKEND\helpers\passport-config' imported from C:\Users\vickey\Downloads\RFREARN_BACKEND\RFREARN_BACKEND\routes\userRoutes.js","at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)","at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:323:11)","at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:916:10)","at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)","at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)","at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)","at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)","at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)"]}

I have checked all the dependencies and paths and it is still giving me this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.